# Spring MVC and HTML 5

Tags: jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

I have a **SpringMVC** application and i am using **Spring Tags**, however i was looking for a solution for taking pictures with a webcam in the application and i found [JQuery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/).

The problem is this uses an element/tag  and **Spring Taglib** does not have a definition for this tag. How can i over come this? I need to use the  tag like a spring tag, or is there a spring tag alternative. Under is an example of how my code functions:

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#canvas").hide();

        $("#camera").webcam({
                width: 320,
                height: 240,
                useMicrophone: false,
                mode: "callback",
                swffile: "resources/swf/jscam_canvas_only.swf",
                quality:85,

                onSave: saveCB,
                onCapture: function () {
                    $("#camera").hide();
                    webcam.save();
                    $("#canvas").show();
                },

                debug: function (type, string) {
                    $("#status").html(type + ": " + string);
                }

        }); 


        $('#upload').click(function () {
            webcam.capture();
            return false;
        });


        window.addEventListener("load", function() {

            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

            if (canvas.getContext) {
                ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 320, 240);
                image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);
            }

            }, false);

});


    <label id="status"></label>                             
                        <div id="camera"></div>

                        <div><p><canvas id="canvas" height="240" width="320"></canvas></p></div>
                        <input  id="upload" type="button" value="Take Photo">
                        <input  id="retake" type="button" value="Re-Take Photo">


                            <ol>
                                <li>
                                    <label>Select Gender</label>
                                    <form:select path="genderId" id="genderId" title="Select Your Gender">
                                    <form:options items = "${gender.genderList}" itemValue="genderId" itemLabel="genderDesc" />
                                    </form:select>
                                    <form:errors path="genderId" class="errors"/>
                                </li>               

                                <li><form:label for="weight" path="weight">Enter Weight <i>(lbs)</i></form:label>
                                    <form:input path="weight" id="weight" title="Enter Weight"/><form:errors path="weight" class="errors"/>
                                </li>
```

Comment: which element/tag you want in spring ?

Comment: <canvas></canvas> is the tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If spring tags dont meet your needs, you could try writing tagx custom tags.  These tags are written in jsp(x), not java, so they are good for rendering arbitrary html.

Comment: can you guide me to an example of creating a custom spring tag

Comment: Document seems to be lacking on these, but there is this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalk.html
To see them in action, have a look at spring ROO, just create a helloworld project and you can see them in action.